# Unable to connect server through Java code by using JSch - RedHat 8 (FIS) Implemented

Tags: java, ssh, redhat, jsch

Expectation
Need to connect AWS server through Java code by using private key.

I was able to log in successfully until **Red Hat 8** implemented in the server end.
If I disable the **FIS (Fuse Integration Service)** then it works as expected.

I'm using IntelliJ for Java code.

Private key format is RSA 3 and I have converted into RSA 2 by using PuTTYgen.

Key pattern is

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption:none
Comment: rsa-key-20220125
Public-Lines:12
AAAn23vnonBIhk......................
..................
....................................
Private-Lines:28
AACABdkfjal905 slknf................
....................................
Private-MAC: nbfajesrkkjnajfnga;alksdnfal;dks
```

Java code is

```java
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity(privatekey)
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
session.setConfig ("StrickHostKeyChecking","no")
session.connect();
```

I am always getting an error

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException : Auth Fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

Log from server end by using Linux command `systemctl status sshd.service`:

```
rexec line 29: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
rexec line 30: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
rexec line 66: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
rexec line 82: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
reprocess config line 66 : Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
reprocess config line 82 : Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
error: Receivved disconnect from <ipaddress> port <id>:3 com.jcrat.jsch.JSchException:Auth fail [preauth]
Disconnected from authenticating user ec2-user <ipaddress> port <id> [preauth]
```

Please find below `tail -f messages` when I log in through PuTTY 0.76 successfully.

```
Reached Target Timers
Reached target Paths
Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket
Reached target Sockets
Reached target Basic System
Reached target default
Startup finished in 324ms
Started User Manager for UID 1000
```

Comment: Yes, I am able to log in through Putty 0.76 version by adding the same key with Pageant

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide us with much information.

Without more information, I can only guess that your server requires rsa-sha2, which is not supported by JSch.

- Either try reconfiguring your allow server to old less-secure "RSA" by adding `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` to `sshd_config`.
- Or use another Java SSH library. There's a fork of JSch that supports rsa-sha2:
  https://github.com/mwiede/jsch

Comment: Given much information more than it required. anyway i will find the solution and let me post out here. at the moment, JSCH will not support FIS which is latest one. we can use alternative instead of JSCH. I shall post here once i have confirmed it